# Javascript loop through array of JSON objects finds instances but records them as undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, pug

I'm running a script within a Pug template. The script begins with reading in an array of JSON objects from MongoDB. The stringified array (`data`) is iterated through to access each JSON object (`doc`) using a for loop. Following this, I iterate through each object's key/value pairs (`col`), of which there are a fixed number (`20`).

```
  var data = !{JSON.stringify(response.features)}

  for(var doc = 0; doc <= data.length; doc++)
    for(var col = 1; col <= 20; col++)
      console.log(data[doc[col]])
```

There are 8 objects with 20 key/value pairs (columns) each. So the fact that I can see 180 returned `undefined` instances signals that the code is working fine, but I can't access or view the returned data for some reason? The end goal for this is to generate a table where each row corresponds to one object's key/value pairs.

Array Format: `Array(8) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]`

Object Format: `Object { _id: "4598hs9h390b", name: "test feature", testValue: 3, … }`

Comment: Your console.log should probably be `console.log(data[doc][col])`.

Comment: On second thought, are you trying to access the object keys through a range of integers 1-20? You can't do that. You need an iterator through the object properties!

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. That log update causes `TypeError: data[doc] is undefined` 160 times. I was previously using a `count` variable in place of `20` which was generated through `Object.keys(data[doc]).length` but this resulted in `TypeError: can't convert undefined to object`.

Comment: What is `var data = !{JSON.stringify(response.features)}` supposed to achieve?

Comment: `var data = !{JSON.stringify(response.features)}` should be: `var data = JSON.parse(response.features)`

Comment: *The stringified array (data) is iterated through to access each JSON object (doc) using a for loop.* Huh? If you have a string an you iterate it, you go character by character of the string. You want to parse the string into an object and iterate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access object properties with indices. What you need to do is use an iterator over the keys like [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Try this to get the data:

```
  var data = !{JSON.stringify(response.features)}

  for(var doc = 0; doc <= data.length; doc++)
    Object.keys(data[doc]).forEach(function(key,index) {
      console.log(data[doc][key])
  });
```

or

```
  var data = !{JSON.stringify(response.features)}

  for(var doc = 0; doc <= data.length; doc++) {
     for(var col of Object.keys(data[doc])) {
        console.log(data[doc][col])
     }
  }
```

Comment: What is `var data = !{JSON.stringify(response.features)}` supposed to achieve?

Comment: This is it - thanks so much Mirodinho! I've genuinely spent well over half of my day fittering about with this!

Answer (score 0):

This is your mistake:

```
console.log(data[doc[col]])
```

is should be:

```
console.log(data[doc][col])
```

Comment: Unfortunately this just returns `TypeError: data[doc] is undefined`, but thanks for answering

Comment: Apologies, this was partly correct - but it was Mirodinho's answer that tied this together for the final solution!